# Databound repeater nested in GridView will not update

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, repeater, databound-controls

I have a `Repeater` nested inside of a `GridView`. On the `RowDataBound` event for the `GridView`, I set the `DataSource` (based on one of the row's columns) and then bind the `Repeater`. This works fine for the initial load, however I need to be able to add new items to the `Repeater` dynamically.

I append an item to the `DataSource`, save it to the `ViewState`, and where I would normally bind using a method call, I bind to the object saved to the `ViewState` instead. The `DataSouce` reflects the change, however the page does not.

What am I missing? I have the exact same setup on another page without the nesting and it works perfectly.

```
if (ViewState["RepeaterObj"]!=null)
{
   rpt.DataSource=(IList<DataTransferObject>)ViewState["RepeaterObj"];
}
else
{
   rpt.DataSource = controller.GetObj(param);
   rpt.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: If I understand your edit correctly, and you have an answer for your question, please post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up resolving the question by cutting out use of the `ViewState` entirely, though I thought my temporary `DataSource` would be lost across the `postback` it wasn't. I ended up going with a class-level `variable` which works perfectly. It seems I didn't properly understand what happens during a `postback`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are not rebinding the the `Repeater`.  You say you change how you bind to look at the `ViewState` object but are you actually triggering the `Bind` to occur?  It sounds like you are not and the page is just reloading with the current data stored with the control's `ViewState`.

Make sure you are calling your `Repeaters` bind event explicitly to sure it is getting rebound.

EDIT: I suspect it might have something to do where you might need to rebind your `GridView` and not just the `Repeater`.

Comment: I am calling the repeater's bind event explicitly. As I mentioned it is almost the same code as the initial page load, just with a different datasource. The bind occurs either way and works normally when using a method to return the datasource rather than pulling it from the viewstate.

Comment: @9ball are you sure your old method of binding isn't getting executed AFTER you are explicitly binding?  Put a break point on the code and see if the old binding is happening afterwards.

Comment: The two bindings are on an if statement, only one executes.

Comment: I think I do need to rebind the `GridView`, but I'm not sure how to do it without an infinite loop happening

Comment: @9ball something is tiggering the need to reload this `Repeater` so bind the whole grid there and then in your `Repeater` `OnDataBinding` do your binding and look for the `ViewState` data for that specific row.  I prefer to not use the `RowDataBound` event and implement databinding at the control level using `OnDataBinding` for the control.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't be storing a datasource in ViewState. That's pretty much the worst place you could put it.

As for your problem, I would suggest either rebinding the GridView when new items are added to the repeater, or find the repeater in the event that saves the new record and rebind it there.

Comment: It isn't actually a substantial `DataSource`, just a list of tags with unique identifiers. I am using the `ViewState` temporarily until the user actually saves their edits. In order to add a new blank item, I have to rebind the repeater to a temporary list. Unless you have a better idea?